# Tire sidewalls if its still okay to ride or not

Tags: tire

Do you think that its still ok to ride the bike (looking at the tire sidewall). Also what are the possible reason why does that happen?

[image: Close-up of rim and sidewall of tire]

Comment: That looks to me like a reflective strip that's coming off. Is that the case? They're only bonded on and not structural

Comment: Looks like it’s just a reflective strip, they are glued on and tend to come off (especially if you run low tire pressures). I’d be more concerned about the angle of the valve stem.

Comment: Do you store the bike outside?  How old is the tyre?

Comment: Nah don't worry about the angle. The reason why its because i turned the front wheel to the side and take the photo in a unrealistic angle which is why the valve stem looks slanted or crooked

Comment: I live in hdb flat. I store it in my living room

Comment: Is the affected strip where there was a logo that has come off?

Answer (score 1):

I would continue to ride that tyre as pictured.

From your photo, the sidewall has a ring of reflective material on each side of the tyre.  This is to make the bike more visible in the dark, and they work quite well for this purpose.

The black rubber of your tyre is a different mixture to the reflective strip, so the strips must be added as a later part of the tyre manufacturing process, after the carbon-black rubber has been pressed in the mold.

I presume that something went wrong with the adhesion, and some part of the reflective ring was flappy, eventually peeling off completely.

I'd expect more of the ring to peel off, at the exposed edges.

Add this site to your monthly bike check, and inspect it frequently.  If the tyre degrades noticeably, bulges out, or anything, then stop and reevaluate.

Answer (score 0):

Cause, could be any number of things from wear and tear to manufacturing fault.
Is it ok to ride, I wouldn't. IMO if you're in any doubt just replace it.